# How can I resume/reload a Python (IDLE) [2.7] shell where it left off?

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, python-idle

In Python 2.7, I am debugging an imported module, using an extensive standing environment in the IDLE shell. I wish to recreate that environment automatically (versus manually typing line-by-line) to ease debugging each time I `Check Module` (triggering an automatic restart in the shell and losing the current state). Is there a way to save shell state, or create a script to re-open the shell [as it was] with a number of commands already run?

This is different from saving a file or script - I wish to restore the shell to the same state it was in previously. For example, if I've executed `import os, numpy`, and assigned several variables `a = 'foo'`, `bar = 229`, I want to restore the shell to the same state of having already imported os, numpy, and assigned `a` and `bar`.

To address comments: Opening a file opens the file in idle; not what I want. Saving a script is fine, but does not restore the state of the shell window.

Comment: you can save your code in a file and open it in IDLE

Comment: If you are repeating the same commands, you can add them all to a script and edit this to remove errors.

Comment: Saving the code in a file just opens it in a new IDLE window. I want the code to execute in the IDLE shell. I am familiar with editing a script - this is not what I want to do. The desire is to *restore the shell* to the same *state* it was in, and leave it in that state. I have edited the original question to reflect these points.

Comment: With the standard interpreter, you'd just pass it the `-i` flag to enter interactive mode after it finishes running the script. I don't know IDLE, but there's probably something equivalent in IDLE.

Comment: if I understand well your intentions, you want that the changes you make to your script be reflected in your IDLE session without the need of reloading the shell/scrip? I certainly can think of a convoluted way of doing something similar to that, but the natural way is making a scrip that reproduce the desire state. To help you with that you can use the option of "File->save as..." but that save everything including the `>>>` that you have to remove to make a working script

Comment: @Copperfield, not helpful. user2357112, Yes, similar to that; thanks for the lead, I'll research that and see what I can find...

Comment: well, give a better example and you may have a better answer, because so far a script is the obvious solution to what you want, that can be in a new file or in the file that you are working on at the end, optionally under the `if __name__ == "__main__"`

Comment: @user2357112 IDLE runs a file from the editor as if it were run with `python -i`.  After the file runs, a `>>> ` prompt appears in Shell.  This feature sometimes trips up beginners who develop a program in IDLE, run it by double clicking the file name, which runs it with just `python` (no `-i`), and wonder why a console window appears and immediately disappears before they can read the output.

Comment: The only way to save the state of a running Python process is to save the Python statements that created the current state.  One can save a Shell session and edit it down to the statements entered.  One can then run the result from the editor to recreate the program state.  Creating programs from interactive experiments is a normal thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a script (e.g. test_this.py), and add all the lines you've typed

```
import os
import numpy
a = 'blah'
bar = 229
```

once done, save and press F5 (run) and it will appear in the IDLE interpreter.  If you have any errors they will appear too, and you can learn to debug.

(Added as reply rather than comment as comments don't allow multi-line scripting)

Comment: This does not answer the question. I am debugging an imported module, using an extensive standing environment in the shell. I wish to recreate that environment automatically each time I test the script and lose the state of the shell. I'll update my question again with this clarification as well.

Comment: @user3.1415927 If you add `import mymod` to a setup script, such as the above, and run it from an editor window, it answers the question as I understood it.  The environment will be recreated, the module to be examined imported, and a prompt given where you can interact with it.

Comment: Omigosh; my humblest apologies - between something wonky in the computer/interpreter state, it *was not* working last night. After a night's sleep, a fresh restart and a clear head, all is working well. Again, my **sincerest** apologies. I've marked your response as the answer, and thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

the obvios and pretty much only solution as mention before is a script, say that you are debugging `mymod.py` then you have the following options

1. Recreate the state in `mymod.py`

   ```
   #my stuff
   ...
   if __name__ == "__main__": 
       import os, numpy
       a = 'blah'
       bar = 229
       print "debugging environment ready"
   ```

   open it with the IDLE and run it (F5) or open it in interactive mode with `python -i mymod.py`
2. make a new script to test it, say `mytest.py`

   ```
   import mymod
   import os, numpy
   a = 'blah'
   bar = 229
   print "debugging environment in outside script ready"
   ```

   and run this instead, in the idle or in interactive mode

In both cases you recreate the desire state in your session and if you want a different state put that in the script.

For example in the idle, with the first one you get

```
================= RESTART: C:\Users\David\Documents\Python Scripts\mymod.py =================
debugging environment ready
>>> a
'blah'
>>> bar
229
>>> os
<module 'os' from 'C:\Python27\lib\os.pyc'>
>>>
```

and the second

```
================ RESTART: C:/Users/David/Documents/Python Scripts/mytest.py ================
debugging environment in outside script ready
>>> a
'blah'
>>> os
<module 'os' from 'C:\Python27\lib\os.pyc'>
>>> bar
229
>>> mymod
<module 'mymod' from 'C:/Users/David/Documents/Python Scripts\mymod.pyc'>
>>>
```

3. a little more convoluted option is doing this in the shell

   ```
   >>> import mymod
   >>> import os, numpy
   >>> a = "blah"
   >>> bar = 229
   ```

   lets say you modify something in mymod.py, for example adding this line `new_stuff = 42`

   ```
   >>> mymod.new_stuff

   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
       mymod.new_stuff
   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'new_stuff'
   >>> import sys
   >>> del sys.modules["mymod"]
   >>> import mymod
   >>> mymod.new_stuff
   42
   >>> a
   'blah'
   ```

   as you see trying to access the new_stuff fail if you don't reload mymod, the solution is re-import mymod, but doing that just access the previously load version so you need to delete that by removing it from sys.modules first.

   Doing this you preserve the state you have, and each time you want to see the changes in mymod you have to do this procedure.

   But beware you may find weird behavior with this method, for example this: lets say that you have this class in mymod.py

   ```
   class A:
       def __init__(self):
           self.a = 42
   ```

   you get that previous instances of this class are not reconoced anymore

   ```
   >>> b = mymod.A()
   >>> del sys.modules["mymod"]
   >>> import mymod
   >>> c = mymod.A()
   >>> b.a
   42
   >>> c.a
   42
   >>> isinstance(b,mymod.A)
   False
   >>> isinstance(c,mymod.A)
   True
   >>> b
   <mymod.A instance at 0x02CA62D8>
   >>> c
   <mymod.A instance at 0x02CE5378>  
   >>>
   ```

Comment: Thank you Copperfield, it appears something was amiss in the system last night. @Lewis-Fogdon's answer was correct, but I've upvoted yours as well, due to its helpfulness. Thank you also for your patience.